# Symfony 4.4 ignores env variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, symfony-4.4

I've just migrated my project from 3.4 to 4.4 and having a trouble to configure it correctly. My project is running inside a Docker container. I provide an env variable *DATABASE_URL* with a production url inside container:

*env | grep DATABASE_URL* - returns a correct value when I run this command inside the container.

Meanwhile my .env file contains:

```
...
DATABASE_URL=dummy-url-for-local-development
```

But when I run *composer dump-env* it takes dummy url instead of the one from the docker container, yet the documentation [clearly states](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/configuration.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-env-files) that

> Any existing env vars are never overwritten by the values defined in .env, so you can combine both.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I expect that any system env var would be prior to what I have in .env file.

Comment: I am interesting by this question. Did you find an answer in the mean time? Can you share some of your bootstrap.php file? I think it's where it's dealing with env vars, and maybe the behaviour here is not in line with what the documentation says.

Answer (score -1):

The `composer dump-env` is only *compiling* **.env** files. It does not look for real environment variables: there could be too many of them, probably unrelated to the Symfony application.

This won't prevent your app from being correctly configured as the system environment variables do take precedence over **.env** files.

You should see the Docker defined value by running:

```sh
./bin/console debug:container --env-vars
```